# Read EXE file description, productname, etc in PHP (Linux Server)

Tags: php, shell

I'm looking for a way to read EXE file details (from Windows machine) on a linux (debian) Server.
I have to display detailed file information (like version-nr, file description, productname, ..) on a php page.

I already found a way to read file Version and Productversion. But I'm stuck while reading the description...

[Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoWZ0.png)

If this is not possible, maybe there is workaround like get those details with a shell script and let PHP work with that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I doubt that an executable file contains a "description" or even a version number of itself as meta information in the file itself. Not on MS-Windows and not on any other operating system. At least not in a uniform way.

Comment: @arkascha: Yes it does. On Windows, a [version information resource](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=588). Obviously the program author has to put it in, but that is the exact info he is asking about.

Comment: On a system with package management you could query that to retrieve the information you are looking for. Linux systems typically use such a management system. So for packages installed in a clean way that database holds meta information. But not for files installed in a "wild" manner as typical for MS-Windows based systems which do _not_ have such a management system.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Thanks, I did not know about that. Seems the idea is to package some minimal information into the executable itself, a strange approach...

Comment: @arkascha: It gets more strange when you need a Windows hotfix from Microsoft and they have you going into the system32 directory and looking at this version info on files to find out what build you have.

Comment: I just found the "ExifTool". I can read all needed details with that!